# Audio's are playing simultaneously issue - Flutter AudioPlayers

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-player

I'm trying to play one music at a time but what currently happening is that multiple audio files are playing simultaneously. Basically there are two screens - one is for listing the all the musics (Inside ListView builder) and second one for playing (this is where music gets played)

When I try to play any other music (when one is already being played), the previous one doesn't stop and both of them get played simultaneously. So what I'm trying to achieve is that previous music should stop automatically when I play any other music

```
// This button is inside the list view builder, when user click on it, it would redirect to Music Player screen where the music is being played

ElevatedButton(
                                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                  primary: Colors.purpleAccent
                                              ),
                                              onPressed: (){
                                                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MusicPlayerScreen(songInfo: snapshot.data![index])));
                                              },
                                              child: Text('PLAY', style: GoogleFonts.oswald(color: Colors.white))
                                          ), 



// Music Screen

class MusicPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final SongInfo songInfo;
  const MusicPlayerScreen({Key? key, required this.songInfo}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MusicPlayerScreen> createState() => _MusicPlayerScreenState();
}

class _MusicPlayerScreenState extends State<MusicPlayerScreen> {

  final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xff313254),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
             
                          await audioPlayer.play(UrlSource(widget.songInfo.filePath));
                          
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50.0,
                        width: 50.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          gradient: const LinearGradient(colors: [
                            Colors.purpleAccent,
                            Colors.purple
                          ]),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.purpleAccent.withOpacity(0.5),
                              spreadRadius: 5,
                              blurRadius: 7,
                              offset: const Offset(0, 3)
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        child: Center(child: Icon(Icons.play_circle_fill, color: Colors.white, size: 35.0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pop this screen you have to dispose the player

```dart
 @override
  void dispose() {
   audioPlayer.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Add this to the MusicPlayerScreen. If you wish to use only stop it when anew music is played you may have to use a common player for all screens and pass it to the musicPlayerScreen and play music on that player itself that way its not duplicated

Comment: I'm aware of dispose but as you mentioned, I want to stop the previous music automatically when new music is being played by the user! Common player for all screen? Could you please demonstrate it?

Comment: Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MusicPlayerScreen(songInfo: snapshot.data![index], audioPlayer: AudioPlayer())));

Comment: Tried the above method too but same outcome! So could you please tell me how to have common player?

Comment: You could define a static field for the audio player inside the class MusicPlayerScreen as: static final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer(); so that you only have a single instance of the AudioPlayer class and use this field as MusicPlayerScreen.audioPlayer each time you need this audioPlayer instance.

Comment: Additionally you can also check if an audio is currently being played and stop(in case any) when playing a new audio in the onTap method of the  InkWell

Comment: Create an audio player in the initstate of the parent class and pass the instance to the music player screen

Comment: @SuvashBhandari bingo! Static did the magic! You are awesome